# Estimate distance of a halogen lamp to simulate sun

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, sun

I'd like to simulate sun effects on a material affected by UV and IR.

Actually is winter and I'll need to wait 6 months to have maximum sun intensity and be able to expose it to direct sun.

I've a halogen lamp of 220W, working at 220V, that is inside a parabolic reflector. Whitout protection glass I've a very similar effect that sun have usually on this kind of material.

What I'd like to know (in a very crude way) is the distance at which the lamp have a similar intensity of the sun.

I don't know if this is possible. Sun intensity also varies. In this case I'll Spain Mediterranean coast as example.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214841/59023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I advise against such experiments because of radiation risks caused by an unshielded halogen bulb. Your halogen light source should not produce much UV because it should have the piece of glass in front of it to block i. If you remove it you run serious risks: ['At a 1 cm distance from the bulb, the UVA and UVB output mirrors that of the sun, while the UVC output far exceeds that of the sun [19]. '](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2829662/#:%7E:text=Halogen%20lamps%20emit%20significant%20levels,bulbs%20with%20the%20lowest%20irradiance.).

If you still want to go ahead you need a safe setup. Glasses and skin covering at least. You will also need a calibrates UV source. Visible intensity can be measured with an app.

Find out how many lumens the sun emits [here](https://kogalla.com/blogs/tech-trail/how-many-lumens-is-the-sun#:%7E:text=For%20every%20watt%20our%20sun,to%20stare%20at%20the%20sun.). Now you need to know the absorption under clear sky conditions, although it also rains in Spain. That depends on the height of the sun. I have seen numbers of 40% absorption for a very clear sky. Next take into account the spread of the light by the angle of illumination by the sun. Reproduce the number of lumens with your source, in UV and in visible light. Again, you will need a safe setup and a calibrated light source. Better wait for the summer!

Comment: Totally cool I never knew those bulbs produced UV, just thought the glass in front was there to protect the bulb from breakage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have an instrument to measure light intensity and apps are not enough precise as I read from some articles. It's curious the statement of 1cm from a halogen lamp where power is not involved. At 1 cm there's probably much more than 100°C , I've measured 50°C at 10cm. Unfortunately I don't have access to the reference paper that states this. Anyway I'll probably wait summer.

Comment: @Singed It was a 50W bulb.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know. I'll do some test between 10 cm and 5 cm . It's not much scientific but based on this statement, lamp power and surface temperature it's somehow a good test in the meantime before summer.